# Compress Rows based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge rows based on multiple columns by VBA.

I have a table like below:

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

What have tried:

I thought to use `Dictionary` and `ArrayList`, but `Dictionary` can not have multiple keys, and for `ArrayList`, I am able to save first table to arraylist, but, can not decide how to create the second based on arraylist.

```
Sub CompressTable(source As Range, target As Range, condition As Range, value As Range)
    Dim objList As Object
    Dim objRow()
    Set objList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For r = 1 To source.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To source.Columns.Count
            If r = 1 Then
                ' add header
                target.Offset(r - 1, c - 1) = source.Cells(r, c)
            Else
                ' not sure how to check whether the col1 + col2 exist
                target.Offset(r - 1, c - 1) = source.Cells(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

More details image
[image]

Comment: @braX please check the update

Comment: In case a non-vba solution works for you, you can resume your data as you wish easily with Pivot Tables

Comment: Please, explain what `source`, `target`, `condition` and `value` should be (as your `Sub` parameters). So, you want returning as in the picture, for as many columns (starting with `Col3` will exist). Is this a correct concise understanding of your question?

Comment: @FaneDuru Do not worry about the code, I just want to get image 2 from image1 which merge col3 and col4 based on col1 and col2

Comment: OK. So, you need to place all columns content, starting from `Col3`, for the pair of `Col1` and `Col2` (User1 S1, User1 S2). S1 - S2 may continue up to Sn. Then, each `S` will have its equivalent value **only on each row**. Is this a correct understanding? I can start preparing an answer only if I can be sure that I understand what you need... Please, extend your example with more rows and more columns. I will be able to deduce what is to be done, if you do not completely explain it in words...

Comment: @FaneDuru I updated more rows, hope it more clear.

Comment: Can't the range have more than 4 columns? Isn't it possible to have more (in real life, I mean)? I asked for **more rows and more columns**...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, the col1 and col2 could be expand to more than 2 columns, and col3 and col4 also can be expand. If I can decide which columns to check same, and which columns to be merge will be much helpful

Comment: Now, you are completely confusing me... What do you mean by **the col1 and col2 could be expand to more than 2 columns**? How the code to know that? Which to be the fix reference to be followed? I thought that the concatenation between first and second column. In such circumstances, I am afraid, I cannot help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and a dictionary and it should be very fast. It is based on the unique keys, built by **concatenation of `Col1` and `Col2`** and is able to process as many columns are in the sheet. The code as it is, returns in the next sheet. You should adapt the code to return where you want/need:

```
Sub CompressTable()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shRet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, dict As Object
 Dim arr, arrH, arrFin, arrItem, a, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strColVal As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet to be processed
 Set shRet = sh.Next  'use here the sheet where the result to be returned

 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row          'last row
 lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
 arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).value 'place the range in an array, for faster iteration
 arrH = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(1, lastCol)).value    'place the headers in an array

 'fill the dictionary for unique keys and items built as concatenation between column number and its value
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    For j = 3 To lastCol
        If arr(i, j) <> "" Then strColVal = j & ";" & arr(i, j)
    Next j
    dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) = dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2)) & "|" & strColVal
 Next
 ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To lastCol): k = 1 'redim the aray to keep the final result and initialize K
 'Place the header in the array
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrH, 2): arrFin(k, i) = arrH(1, i): Next i: k = k + 1
 'process the dictionary keys and items:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arrFin(k, 1) = Split(dict.Keys()(i), "|")(0): arrFin(k, 2) = Split(dict.Keys()(i), "|")(1)
    arrItem = Split(dict.items()(i), "|")
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrItem)
        a = Split(arrItem(j), ";")
        arrFin(k, CLng(a(0))) = CLng(a(1))
    Next j
    k = k + 1
 Next
 'drop the final array content at once:
 shRet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
 shRet.Activate
 MsgBox "Ready...)"
End Sub
```

If you really need to expand `Co1` to `Col2` range, to build the unique keys, you can try that only using relevant headers name and change a little the code logic, in order to use so built keys and iterate starting after the last column used for building a key...

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, consider using Pivot Tables (and probably you can do it this way with VBA too).

[image]

Create Pivot Table and then:

1. Take your criteria columns (in example, Col1 and Col2) into rows section
2. Take your Values (Col3 and Col4) into Values section and choose **Sum Function**
3. Remove subtotals, grand totals and apply tabular design.

IT takes seconds and it will return the output you are looking for. And if you got Excel 2010 or higher you can add an extra option, repeat item labels so there will be not blanks in Col1:

[Repeat item labels in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repeat-item-labels-in-a-pivottable-882bdb55-9cdc-4d8d-b531-8e96e41dea31)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will not work if the "source" table is expanded,
because the code assumes the column to be checked/matched is col-1 and col-2 only and the value of the matched row to be as the result is from col-3 and col-4 only.

The result is put in column H of the same sheet. Change as your need.
Sub test()

```
Set rg = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rg: arr.Item(cell.Value & "-" & cell.Offset(0, 1)) = 1: Next

'Range("F:M").Clear

For Each el In arr
Set oStart = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
usr = Split(el, "-")(0)
s = Split(el, "-")(1)

Set c = rg.Find(usr, lookat:=xlWhole)
FirstAddress = c.Address

Do
If c.Offset(0, 1).Value = s Then
    oStart.Offset(0, 0).Value = usr
    oStart.Offset(0, 1).Value = s

    With oStart.Offset(0, 2)
    If .Value = "" Then .Value = c.Offset(0, 2)
    End With

    With oStart.Offset(0, 3)
    If .Value = "" Then .Value = c.Offset(0, 3)
    End With
End If
Set c = rg.FindNext(c)
Loop While c.Address <> FirstAddress

Next el
End Sub
```

[image]

So, the code won't work if the "source" table dynamically always change. For example, later on the table is changed to something like this :

[image]

If the "source" table is always fixed, but the image you attached is just for example (2 columns to be matched, another 2 columns for the value), then the code is still can be modified.